# Get alerts for new activity on your questions?

Tags: support

Is there a setting or something that I'm missing to send me *instant* alerts when a question I asked receives new activity?  I mean I get a little "toast" notification on the inbox when I visit the site, but if I don't visit or constantly check-up on the site, I miss things.  I'd like to get an email notification or something as soon as someone posts an answer or a new comment on my questions.

Comment: cross site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/e-mail-notifications-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Go to your profile then click on "Edit Profile and Settings" then click "Preferences"

You can also get the [Stackexchange app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en) which will notify you fairly quickly (not sure about the sync rate exactly)

Or, if you're one of *those* peopele, you might be interested in the [stackexchange app for Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8)

Comment: Yes I have that set.  I guess I should have been more clear - looking for instant notification.  I've edited the original question to specify.

Comment: Other than using the app (which I have edited into the question in case you were unaware), I don't think there's any way to get notified any faster.

Comment: +1 for the [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/291223)

Comment: @NathanOliver I knew the hard work of my latest edit would be worth the trouble ;)

Comment: @codeMagic stack exchange app sounds good. I was unaware this existed.  Thanks!

Comment: What about desktop alerts instead of emails? Desktop alerts can give users to get notified and can help them to solve their problem ASAP