# Idea! - To invite OP follow-up on their question

Tags: feature-request

**What if** an email was sent to OP when there is activity on their question?

It could be sent only if they aren't logged in (this could be a user preference). It could be a day's digest for comments (to prevent too much email sending).

It should be a different message for comments and answers. So answer notification email would be sent instantly (not waiting the for digest).

**Why?**

Because I think it would invite OPs to mark their answer as accepted. Sometimes, OP take days and weeks to come back to see if they had an answer. 
And sometimes, they never come back... Leaving lots of unaccepted answers.

I think and hope it is simple to implement. ;)

Comment: Doesn't this already exist?

Comment: If so, I did not find it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you are looking at `users/preferences/id`

Comment: Okay... This link is my answer : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297702/get-alerts-for-new-activity-on-your-questions Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Were you looking for this checkbox?

[image: asdf]

If it doesn't appear, go to [your account preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and make sure "Email me my unread inbox messages" is checked.